# Passkit Pull To Refresh PKZIP error

Tags: php, passbook, passkit

when trying to update a pass in passbook by using my web server, I get an error message:

```
Apr 18 23:56:17 ISARFAKTOR passd[493] <Warning>: Get pass task (pass type pass.de.isarfaktor.medifaktor, serial number 139785475117, if-modified-since (null); with web service url http://api.medifaktor.de/webservice) got response with code 200
Apr 18 23:56:17 ISARFAKTOR passd[493] <Warning>: BOM could not extract archive: Couldn't read PKZip signature
Apr 18 23:56:17 ISARFAKTOR passd[493] <Warning>: Get pass task (pass type pass.de.isarfaktor.medifaktor, serial number 139785475117, if-modified-since (null); with web service url http://api.medifaktor.de/webservice) encountered error: Received invalid pass data (Diese Karte kann nicht gelesen werden, da sie ungültig ist.)
```

This surprises me, because the creation and loading of the pass itself works perfectly fine. Only if I use the pull to refresh, I get the error messages. I don't have a clue why it shouldn't work here. I already checked the Database output, that is received when the update method is searching for an existing pass. Everything fine with the pass.json as well. Do I miss anything?

Sebastian

Comment: Are you sure that this method is returning a .pkpass bundle? One way to check is to use curl to spoof the request and see what you are getting back.

Comment: Interesting your not returning a date for if-modified-since.